# Invoking Liferay's themeDisplay object within freemarker template

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, freemarker

I need to access the themeDisplay object in a customized freemarker template.

I tried to do it like this:

```
${themeDisplay.getLanguageId()}
```

But i get the following error message:

```
Expression themeDisplay is undefined on line 208, column 18
```

I also tried to add this two lines in my portal-ext.properties but without success:

```
freemarker.engine.restricted.classes=
freemarker.engine.restricted.variables=
```

Is there a successful approach for doing this ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I hope u tried with $themeDisplay.getLanguageId()

Comment: `$themeDisplay.getLanguageId()` does not evaluate the variable. It just prints it like it was a simple string like "hello my name is gustav".

Comment: Google `liferay freemarker themeDisplay`, the very first result says you have to use `<#assign themeDisplay = objectUtil("com.liferay.portal.theme.ThemeDisplay") />`

Comment: First of all Sorry Shivam for my rude comment.

Comment: `<#assign themeDisplay =    bjectUtil("com.liferay.portal.theme.ThemeDisplay") /> 
 ${themeDisplay}
 ${themeDisplay.getLanguageId()}` Thanks, i tried it this way but got the following error message: Expression `themeDisplay.getLanguageId()`is undefined.

Comment: `${themeDisplay}`shows the following output  `com.liferay.portal.theme.ThemeDisplay@333f6d20 So it seems the themeDisplay object was created...

Comment: `${themeDisplay.getLanguageId()}` should work. It works for me in a custom ADT tested in Liferay 7 CE. I didn't even need to assign it first, as it is already in the context. What Liferay version do you have? What kind of template? Is it a WebContent template, an ADT, a theme template?

Comment: @HelmutSteiner To add on to Juan's comments,it seems like a bug,working in 7 perfectly fine.I am using 6.2-ce-ga-2

Comment: @JuanManuelRogado Hi Juan Manuel, we are using Liferay 6.2 EE with a WebContent template. We are not using ADT.

Comment: @ShivamAggarwal Do you know a workaround for this bug ?

Comment: @HelmutSteiner Sorry nothing that I have on this so far.

Comment: If `themeDisplay` somehow cannot be accessed, try `locale.getLanguage()`. The `locale` variable should be available for web content templates too.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a version of theme display from request, just like this: <#assign themeDisplay = request['theme-display'] />.

But be carefull, this is only a lite version, so you can get the plid value: themeDisplay['plid'], but you can't get the layout object (themeDisplay.getLayout()).

All depends of what you want to do with the object.
Regards

Note: this is only in 6.2 CE, it seems that in Liferay 7 the themeDisplay is complete and an implicit variable.